# How to scroll text widget with scrollbar and bind them together?

Tags: python

I try set scrollbar to text widget but my text widget doesn't respond to ycsroll of my scrollbar
Here is my code:

```
Sb.Scrollbar(root,comand=text widget.yview())
Text widget.configure(yscrollcomand=sb.set)
```

I tried it with my code and used this syntax many times, but this is the first time it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is a space in between your function for your scrollbar command. The function `text widget.yview()`has a space between text and widget. Another problem is that when you spelled command wrong. You spelled `comand`. You also don't include parenthesis of the function for the command.